# Fetching data from Firebase in React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I came across a `map` in Firebase. I have done the following structure in Firestore.

[image: in firebase]

I want to read the state whether it is liked or not, corresponding to the user uid -

```
   onLike() {
     let list = this.props.list

     let uid = this.state.user.uid

     list.uid.liked = !list.uid.liked

     list.likes = list.uid.liked ? list.likes + 1 : list.likes - 1

     this.props.updateList(list);
   }
```

I think there is a mistake calling the user uid itself,
I receive the error saying can't find variable and undefined object, please educate on the same.

Comment: 1. Firestore doesn't allow fetching partial documents.
2. It'd be helpful if you could show the snippet where you make a call to Firestore.

Comment: 1. Yes buddy i saw that firestore doesnt allow partial document fetches 2. firebase.firestore().collection("categories").doc("1234").collection("celebrities"); this is the call, i rendered it to a list to use it in another screen.

Answer (score 0):

Hi finally i figured out how to do it but modified a little,changed the write method as value itself not as map function,thanks to a javascript forum, the final code is as follows

```
  onLike(){


  let uid = this.state.user.uid;

  let list = this.props.list

  var liked = uid +'liked'

  list[liked] = !list[liked]

  list.likes = list[liked] ? list.likes + 1 : list.likes - 1

  this.props.updateList(list);
  };
```